# how to config temporal S3 authentication in temporal helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-s3, kubernetes-helm, temporal-workflow

I installed temporal using helm chart from below link:

https://github.com/temporalio/helm-charts

**helm command was:**

#helmstage upgrade --install -f values/values.archival.s3.yaml  -f values/values.mysql.yaml   temporal-test . -n test

everything was ok and service deployed successfully.

then i updated values/values.archival.s3.yaml as below:

```
server:
  archival:
    history:
      state: "enabled"
      enableRead: true
      provider:
        s3store:
          region: "default"
          endpoint: "http://ceph-infra-s3:8080"
          s3ForcePathStyle: true
    visibility:
      state: "enabled"
      enableRead: true
      provider:
        s3store:
          region: "default"
          endpoint: "http://ceph-infra-s3:8080"
          s3ForcePathStyle: true

  namespaceDefaults:
    archival:
      history:
        state: "enabled"
        URI: "s3://temporal-development"
      visibility:
        state: "enabled"
        URI: "s3://temporal-development"
```

but i don't now how and where can i config s3 authentication accesskey and secretkey.

should i create a secret? if yes where can i use the created secret ?

Answer (score 0):

In your values.yml file under the server block there's an additional envs block. There you can add the aws access and secret keys as specified in the [aws go sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/configuring-sdk.html#specifying-credentials)

```
server:
  additionalEnvs:
    - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      value: <your access key id>
    - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      value: <your secret access key>
```